# Which VC Runtime is required for specific scenario?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

When I use visual studio 2019 latest platform toolset and set target platform as Windows 7/8.1 to create an executable, then which VC Runtime is required to present in order to run the application executable on the target machine? Should it be corresponding to Windows 10 OR Windows 7/8.1

Any explanation in this regard please?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the Windows target, only the toolset version.  So latest.

Comment: What latest? My target machine is win8.1 or 7. What do you mean when you say 'latest' ? What should be present on machine where I run such executable?

Comment: It is very unclear why you persist naming the Windows version and why you tagged this question with [visual-studio-2012].  Just use [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/determining-which-dlls-to-redistribute?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Visual studio (2012 as well) has property to set the target platform for it's project. the target platform refers to windows version which your target will be. Can you ask me what unclear to you and I will respond.

Answer (score 0):

The VS 2019 REDIST that matches the version of Visual Studio 2019 you are using is all that's required on the target machine as long as you restrict your program to using the APIs present on Windows 7/Windows 8.1. This is typically enforced by using a preprocessor symbol of `_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601` (Windows 7).

See [Using the Windows Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers)